# A question about transcendental extensions

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, transcendence-theory

Consider an extension $K/F$. Suppose $S \subset K$ such that $S$ is algebraically independent over $F$. Prove that each $s \in S$ is transcendental over $F(S-\{s\})$.

How do I prove this claim? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of an algebraically independent set?

Comment: Apologies for not including it in the original question! Given an extension $K/F$, a subset $A=\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ is algebraically independent over $F$, if there is a non-zero polynomial $f(x_1,...,x_n) \in F[x_1,...,x_n]$ such that $f(a_1,...,a_n)=0$. An arbitrary subset $S$ of $K$ is called algebraically independent over $F$ if every finite subset of $S$ is algebraically independent over $F$.

Comment: Well, for simplicity let's assume $S=\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ and $s=a_n$. The infinite case is no different. If $s$ was algebraic over $F(a_1,...,a_{n-1})$ then it would satisfy an equation $s^n+\frac{f_{n-1}(a_1,...,a_{n-1})}{g_{n-1}(a_1,...,a_{n-1})}s^{n-1}+...+\frac{f_0(a_1,...,a_{n-1})}{g_0(a_1,...,a_{n-1})}=0$. Multiply by a common denominator to get an equation of the form $h_n(a_1,...,a_{n-1})s^n+...+h_1(a_1,...,a_{n-1})s+h_0(a_1,...,a_{n-1})=0$, where $h_0,...,h_n$ are polynomials in $F[a_1,...,a_{n-1}]$. Now use the fact that $S$ is algebraically independent to get a contradiction.